# How to get recent my all active chat rooms

Tags: support, chat

A few days ago I chatted with one Stack Overflow user, but the problem is I did not find that chat room. I was chatting with an question thread.  There have been a lot of valuable chat log messages for me.

Is there a way to get my recent active chat room?

Comment: you can go to your chat profile and recent tab to see your chat log.. go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com and then on your username on the top right corner

Answer (score 5):

Bringing over the first part of my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298588/158100) on MSE:

> You have a chat account on a chat server. In the network, there are 3
>   servers:
>
> - Stack Overflow Chat
>
>   - for all users of Stack Overflow
> - Stack Exchange Chat
>
>   - for all users of all other sites in the SE network
> - Meta Stack Exchange Chat
>
>   - for users of Meta Stack Exchange
>
> Each chat server has their own collection of user accounts, you don't
>   necessarily have an account on all three. To find rooms you've
>   participated in, visit all three servers (or at least verify you
>   picked the right one).
>
> From the topbar you can open the site navigator and then find a link
>   to chat for your current community. Clicking it brings you on a chat
>   server that belongs to the site you're on.
>
> In the chat topbar you'll find your username. Clicking it brings you
>   to your [chat
>   profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4415445/) of the
>   specific chat server.  If you're on the *General* tab you'll find on
>   the right of the page two subtabs: *rooms you're currently in* and
>   *rooms you're frequently in*. On the left, you see the rooms you are an owner in.
>
> If you don't find any rooms on that page, you can check for [recent
>   messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4415445/?tab=recent)
>   and if that is also without success you're last hope is
>   [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248541/158100) )

You can reach your chat profile if you're logged in by clicking your username in the topbar:

[image]

Comment: from https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ is there a **clickable menu item**? Or I must go in and **manually type** my own username in the addressbar to make it work? ie is there anything clickable that would direct me to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5175709 or https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5175709?tab=recent

Comment: @Honey I've added a screenshot with a red free hand circle. Is that what you're looking for or did I miss what your comment is about?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Just in the last 2 weeks, I've learned that I can enlarge the comment box, Stackoverflow shortcuts, (and just now) access my chat history page easier. This is all after 3 years of using stackoverflow...

Comment: @Honey top tip: that history page only shows page 1 of your recent history. There is a hidden feature that allows you to go more pages back: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5175709?tab=recent&page=8 but you would need to add the &page=42 yourself. No easy clicks here ....

Comment: @Adinia seeing most of this post is a quote I think it would be apropriate to also edit [the source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298575/how-do-i-find-chat-rooms-ive-participated-in-previously/298588#298588) :)

Comment: @AndréKool That's probably right, but I don't really like to go and edit old posts, and bump them on the main page if it's not really necessary. What caught my eye here was the "your/you're" mistake that the OP just added, outside the quote.